# How to display one field from a model in Django template

Tags: python, django

I've inherited a Django project to maintain, and despite having done the tutorial, I'm feeling kind of lost when I am wading through all this project code and have just a general lack of understanding as soon as I hit templates.

I have a model called Student, defined like

```
class Student(models.model);
True
studentID = models.CharField(max_length = 6, primary_key = True)
age = models.IntegerField()
```

along with a few other fields omitted for brevity.

Now, I have a HTML file for the webpage on which I want to display the current student's score (current student is defined as the one currently accessing the page, identified by their student ID) 
in views.py, I get the current student by

```
currentStudent = Student.objects.get(studentID = request.session['studentID'])
```

My question: in my HTML file, how do I display the current student's age in part of a text block?

Comment: Can you share the view function you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django takes your html files and fills in the blanks.

you tell it where the blanks are using double brackets `{{ somevar }}` or one of the many built-in tags (such as 'for') which look like this `{% sometag %}`. It takes some time learning how to work with this, and learning about all the options you have ([the docs are great](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/)), but it's very easy to understand the basics. Here are a bunch of examples:

views.py

```
def example(request):
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'myvar': 'hello world'}
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <h1> {{ myvar }} </h1>    
</body>
```

result:

```
<body>
  <h1> hello world </h1>    
</body>
```

as you can see, render_to_response takes a template name and then fills in the blanks. It takes index.html, looks at the context dictionary, finds every appearence of `{{ myvar }}` and replaces that with `hello world`.

Say I have a model named `MyModel` which has a field `MyData`? To display it, simply send it with context:

```
def example(request):
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'myvar': MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)}
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <h1> {{ myvar.MyData }} </h1>    
</body>
```

Second example:

views.py

```
def example_fortag(request):
    template = 'fortag.html'
    context = {'mylist': [1, 2, 3]}
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

fortag.html

```
<body>
{% for item in mylist %}
    <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
{% endfor %}  
</body>
```

The result would look like this:

```
<body>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h1>3</h1> 
</body>
```

Get it? Here's an example using the if tag:

views.py:

```
def example_iftag(request):
    template = 'iftag.html'
    context = {'mylist': range(1, 10)}
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

iftag.html:

```
<body>
{% for item in mylist %}
    {% if item / 2 == 0 %} 
        <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}  
</body>
```

The result would look like this:

```
<body>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h1>4</h1>
  <h1>6</h1>
  <h1>8</h1>
</body>
```

You can also do complicated stuff. Say you send in a dictionary as a variable:

```
context = {'myvar': {'key': 'value'}}
```

you can do this:

```
{% for key, value in myvar.items %}
 ... etc ...
```

See? I'm using the items function, which is a built-in of the dictionary object in python language (note I don't need to call the function with `()`).

With all that in mind, I strongly suggest you go over the [third part of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) one more time and pick it up slowly. Django's template language is pretty intuitive and very powerful, hope this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

first you need to pass that variable to template in context. But if its already there then something like

```
{{ currentStudent.age }}
```

will work just fine

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to "pass that variable to template in context"?

Comment: I think you should work your way through the tutorial. Relevant part of tutorial is here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render.