# Calling a field from a model in template other than url pattern not working

Tags: python, django, templates, foreign-keys

I'm new to Django and programming. I'm trying to call the field from a model through a template other than specified in my url patterns but I keep on getting a blank display in the div block I want i to display in. I want a list of categories to be displayed in the left side-bar. I have looked at many answers on SO [Django foreign key relation in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281965/django-foreign-key-relation-in-template) and [How to display one field from a model in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806934/how-to-display-one-field-from-a-model-in-django-template) and Ive worked through the Django docs.

I've created a list of categories in the admin class. The code is working as intended but Im not able to extend this list to be displayed from the base.html template class so that I have category navigation throughout.

I have two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name='topic')
    ...

class Categories(models.Model):
    topics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

Here is my view which works in the 'categories.html' template

```
def categories(request):
category = Categories.objects.all()
return render(request, 'posts/categories.html', {"category": category})
```

The url pattern related to it

```
url(r'^categories/$', views.categories, name='category'),
```

Here is how i'm calling the field

```
{% for field in category %}

    <div class="col-sm-10"><a href="#">{{ field.topics }}</a></div>

{% endfor %}
```

I've tried alot of different approaches such as:

```
{% for field in category.topic.all %}

{% endfor %}
```

Please assist. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have data for categories? In your view add this: `print(len(category))` and look at terminal to see how many items there are in the database.

Comment: I have 20 items that I added to categories in admin and they appear in my post-form as a drop-down list. Im just unsure of how to access them otherwise.